# how to check nothing has changed in cucumber?

Tags: cucumber, bdd, specflow, gherkin

The business scenario I'm trying to test with cucumber/gherkin (specflow, actually) is that given a set of inputs on a web form, I make a request, and need to ensure that (under certain conditions), when the result is returned, a particular field hasn't changed (under other condition, it does). E.g.

Given I am on the data entry screen
When I select "do not update frobnicator"
And I submit the form
And the result is displayed
Then the frobnicator is not updated

How would I write the step "the frobnicator is not updated"?

One option is to have a step that runs before "I submit the form" that reads something like "I remember the value of the frobnicator", but that's a bit rubbish - it's a horrible leak of an implementation detail. It distracts from the test, and is not how the business would describe this. In fact, I have to explain such a line any time anyone sees it.

Does anyone have any ideas on how this could be implemented a bit nicer, ideally as written?

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the previous answer.
The gherkin text you *felt* like you wanted to write is probably right.
I'm going to modify it *just a little* to make it so that the `When` step is the specific action that is being tested.

```
Given I am on the data entry screen
And I have selected "do not update frobnicator"
When I submit the form
Then the frobnicator is not updated
```

How *exactly* you Assert the result will depend on how your program updates the frobnicator, and what options that gives you.. but to show it is possible, I'll assume you have decoupled your data access layer from your UI and are able to mock it - and therefore monitor updates.

The mock syntax I am using is from Moq.

...

```
private DataEntryScreen _testee;

[Given(@"I am on the data entry screen")] 
public void SetUpDataEntryScreen()
{
    var dataService = new Mock<IDataAccessLayer>();
    var frobby = new Mock<IFrobnicator>();

    dataService.Setup(x => x.SaveRecord(It.IsAny<IFrobnicator>())).Verifiable(); 
    ScenarioContext.Current.Set(dataService, "mockDataService");

    _testee = new DataEntryScreen(dataService.Object, frobby.Object);
}
```

The important thing to note here, is that the given step sets up the object we are testing with ALL the things it needs...  We didn't need a separate clunky step to say "and i have a frobnicator that i'm going to memorise" - that would be bad for the stakeholders *and bad for your code flexibility*.

```
[Given(@"I have selected ""do not update frobnicator""")]
public void FrobnicatorUpdateIsSwitchedOff()
{
    _testee.Settings.FrobnicatorUpdate = false;
}

[When(@"I submit the form")]
public void Submit()
{
    _testee.Submit();
}

[Then(@"the frobnicator is not updated")]
public void CheckFrobnicatorUpdates()
{
    var dataService = ScenarioContext.Current.Get<Mock<IDataAccessLayer>>("mockDataService");

    dataService.Verify(x => x.SaveRecord(It.IsAny<IFrobnicator>()), Times.Never);
}
```

Adapt the principle of Arrange, Act, Assert depending on your circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Think about how you would test it manually:

```
Given I am on the data entry screen
And the blah is set to "foo"
When I set the blah to "bar"
And I select "do not update frobnicator"
And I submit the form
Then the blah should be "foo"
```